# Getting files/content/assets from nuget packages

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

When a Visual Studio project uses , how can I access files that are part of the package?
For example, "Newtonsoft.Json" V12.0.3 contains several files besides Newtonsoft.Json.Dll - such as `newtonsoft.json\12.0.3\lib\net20\Newtonsoft.Json.xml` and `newtonsoft.json\12.0.3\LICENSE.md`.

I found `GeneratePathProperty` - which is great, but it doesn't work when building SDK projects inside VS2017. (When building old style framework projects, it does work).

`<IncludeAssets>` doesn't appear to do anything.

Part of my csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" GeneratePathProperty="true">
        <IncludeAssets>all</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>

</Project>
```

Now, if I build from the command line (msbuild.exe 15.9.21+g9802d43bc3) 
`msbuild /t:Restore;Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU" MyProject.sln`

`MyProject.csproj.nuget.g.props` contains

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(ExcludeRestorePackageImports)' != 'true' ">
    <PkgNewtonsoft_Json Condition=" '$(PkgNewtonsoft_Json)' == '' ">%userprofile%\.nuget\packages\newtonsoft.json\12.0.3</PkgNewtonsoft_Json>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Which is great, because I can use $(PkgNewtonsoft_Json) in my project file as needed to get those files.

But, when I build from inside VS2017 (V15.9.17), my *PROPS file does not get this symbol defined :-(

-------- **Update** --------

OK, after rebooting and trying again it worked :-)
I had to change `Targets="restore;build"` to `Targets="restore;"` or I would get errors. Given Lib1 and Lib2, where Lib2 depends on Lib1, I get this error

```
Target CoreCompile:
  Using shared compilation with compiler from directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn
  CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\src\...\build\Lib2\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\Lib2.dll' could not be found
Done building target "CoreCompile" in project "Lib1.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

Then, after building the whole solution - it fails, and when I build Lib1 again it fails with

````
error MSB4006: There is a circular dependency in the target dependency graph involving target "Build".```
````

Comment: I think it is an issue about restore format between `msbuild -t:restore` and `nuget -t:restore` which is the restore format in VS IDE.

Comment: What is a "restore format"?

I've implemented "CopyPackages" from https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4837 . Seems a bit ugly to me, but it at least works.

Comment: In a deep research and test, this is an issue in VS 2017 IDE and  in the latest VS2019, it has been fixed.

Comment: I just tried - it doesn't appear to do anything.
With VS2019, the solution works as is.
With VS2017, your fix it doesn't appear to do anything - doesn't work.

Comment: ```1>Target OnceBuild:
1>  Target ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
1>    Building solution configuration "Release|AnyCPU".
1>  Target Restore:
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets(114,5): warning : Unable to find a project to restore!
1>  Done building target "Restore" in project "MyProject.sln".
1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which is great, because I can use $(PkgNewtonsoft_Json) in my project
>   file as needed to get those files. But, when I build from inside
>   VS2017 (V15.9.17), my *PROPS file does not get this symbol defined

**In a deep research and test**, I found that it is just an issue in VS2017 IDE while VS2019 has been fixed that issue.

`xxx.csproj.nuget.g.props` is generated by the **restore** process. And in VS2017, for projects with the new SDK, restore package mechanism of VS IDE which is different from msbuild restore mechanism had a large incompatibility problem, resulting in various situations. Fortunately, VS2019 fixes this problem.

[image]

**As a suggestion**, you could try these steps:

**1)** download [the latest VS2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/) and use it.

**2)** add a custom target  which contains a task to use MSBuild to build your project into `xxxxx.csproj file`.

```
<Target Name="OnceBuild" AfterTargets="Build">

    <MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionDir)$(SolutionFileName)" Targets="restore;build" Properties="Configuration=Release;Platform=Any CPU">        
    </MSBuild>   
 </Target>
```

It will generate the `xxx.csproj.nuget.g.props` which is created by `MSBuild restore`.  Although this contains an error MSB4006, it won't affect the build process in the VS IDE and you do not have to worry about it.

**Update 1**

Just add a custom target to run `msbuild -t:store` in MSBuild

```
<Target Name="OnceBuild" AfterTargets="Build">    
  <MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionDir)$(SolutionFileName)" Targets="restore" Properties="Configuration=Release;Platform=Any CPU">        
   </MSBuild>   
</Target>
```